# Nestjs circular dependency using Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

Inside a nestJs app using mongoose, when the app is running i don't have any trouble.
But i want to write unit testing using jest and there is a problem in that case.

I simplify the code to focus on the problem, there is my test file:

```
// client.controller.spec.ts
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { PrivateClientService } from '../client.service'
import { responseMock } from '@test/mocks/response.mock'

jest.mock('../client.service')

describe('PrivateClientController', () => {
  let privateClientService: PrivateClientService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    console.log(responseMock) // Import with alias works
    
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      // controllers: [],
      providers: [PrivateClientService],
    }).compile()
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  describe('createClient', () => {
    it('should passed', () => {
      expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
  })
})
```

When i run the following test above i have this error:

```
src/framework/features/client/private/test/client.controller.spec.ts
  PrivateClientController
    createClient
      ✕ should passed (14 ms)

  ● PrivateClientController › createClient › should passed

    A circular dependency has been detected inside RootTestModule. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()". Note that circular relationships between custom providers (e.g., factories) are not supported since functions cannot be called more than once.

      18 |     console.log(responseMock)
      19 |     
    > 20 |     const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
         |                       ^
      21 |       imports: [],
      22 |       // controllers: [PrivateClientController],
      23 |       providers: [PrivateClientService],

      at NestContainer.addProvider (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/container.js:146:19)
      at DependenciesScanner.insertProvider (node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:235:35)
      at node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:119:18
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at DependenciesScanner.reflectProviders (node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:118:19)
      at DependenciesScanner.scanModulesForDependencies (node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:99:18)
      at async DependenciesScanner.scan (node_modules/@nestjs/core/scanner.js:31:9)
      at async TestingModuleBuilder.compile (node_modules/@nestjs/testing/testing-module.builder.js:70:9)
      at async Object.<anonymous> (src/framework/features/client/private/test/client.controller.spec.ts:20:23)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.778 s, estimated 1 s
```

If i comment the following line, the test passed.

```
// providers: [PrivateClientService],
```

So, my guess is, it's come from `PrivateClientService`, but after a lot of research i don't understand or find why.

```
// client.service.ts
import { Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common'
import { isValidObjectId } from 'mongoose'

import { InvalidObjectIdException } from '@framework/exceptions/InvalidObjectId.exception'

import { Client } from '../schemas/client.schema'
import { ClientRepository } from '../client.repository'

@Injectable()
export class PrivateClientService {
  constructor(private readonly clientRepository: ClientRepository) {}

  async createClient(client: Client): Promise<Client> {
    const newClient = await this.clientRepository.create(client)

    return newClient
  }

  async updateClient(id: string, client: Client): Promise<Client> {
    if (!isValidObjectId(id)) throw new InvalidObjectIdException()

    const updatedClient = await this.clientRepository.findByIdAndUpdate(id, client)

    if (!updatedClient) {
      throw new NotFoundException()
    }

    return updatedClient
  }

  async deleteClient(id: string): Promise<Client> {
    if (!isValidObjectId(id)) throw new InvalidObjectIdException()

    const client = await this.clientRepository.findByIdAndDelete(id)

    if (!client) {
      throw new NotFoundException()
    }

    return client
  }
}
```

I'm pretty new to nestjs/nodeJs, for those who wonder i follow this exact [repo architecture](https://github.com/mguay22/nestjs-mongo/blob/unit-testing/src/users/test/users.controller.spec.ts).

At this time, i try to:

- forwardRef the constructor in `PrivateClientService`
- comment the two import for client.schema and client.repository inside
  `PrivateClientService`
- I have check if the import alias works fine (yes)
- Keep hope

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem!**

The jest mock line i think automatically use the `__mocks__` folder:

```
jest.mock('../client.service')
```

But inside my mock there is my file:

```
// __mocks__/client.service.ts
import { clientStub } from '../test/stubs/client.stub'

export const clientService = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  createClient: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(clientStub()),
  updateClient: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(clientStub()),
  deleteClient: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(clientStub()),
})
```

But i need to name it to match the auto import, so rename `clientService` to `PrivateClientService`.

And the test passed with the imports :)